# Function not returning proper values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a function below that should return standardized outputs based on numeric ranges:

```
`def incident(count):
if count['incident_ct']<= 4: 
    val = 1 
elif count['incident_ct']>4 & count['incident_ct']<= 13: # 25 to 50%
    val = 2
elif count['incident_ct'] >13 & count['incident_ct']<=31: # 50 to 75%
    val = 4
elif count['incident_ct'] >31 & count['incident_ct']<=100: # 75 to 95%
    val = 8
else: 
    val = 16
return val`
```

Then applied to new row in the data:

```
`intersections['v_counts'] = intersections.apply(incident, axis = 1)`
```

However, the output is not giving what I specified in the ranges (only 1 or 2 in the v_count)
When looking at my code, the incident_ct = **34** should be **8** and where incident_ct = **172** should be  **16**
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try use `pd.cut`

```
pd.cut(intersections['incident_ct'],bins=[4,13,31,100,..],labels=[1,2,4,8,16])
```

Fix your code

```
def incident(count):
...     if count['incident_ct']<= 4:
...         val = 1
...     elif count['incident_ct']>4 and count['incident_ct']<= 13: # 25 to 50%
...         val = 2
...     elif count['incident_ct'] >13 and count['incident_ct']<=31: # 50 to 75%
...         val = 4
...     elif count['incident_ct'] >31 and count['incident_ct']<=100: # 75 to 95%
...         val = 8
...     else:
...         val = 16
...     return val
```

Comment: ok this works to an extent but there are a couple more variables where I will be using conditions from multiple columns. I'd prefer if I can get this if-else function to work properly and not use pd.cut. Do you have any torubleshooting recommendations?

Comment: that was it! I also just figured out another simple way by adding ( ) between the &.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses if using the '&'
    `def incident(count):
    if count['incident_ct']<= 4: # lowest percent
        val = 1 
    elif (count['incident_ct']>4) & (count['incident_ct']<= 13): # 25 to 50%
        val = 2
    elif (count['incident_ct'] >13) & (count['incident_ct']<=31): # 50 to 75%
        val = 4
    elif (count['incident_ct'] >31) & (count['incident_ct']<=100): # 75 to 95%
        val = 8
    else: # upper 5%
        val = 16
    return val`